# How does Wordpress get the enhanced form controls in their UI?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, css

I've been looking for a simple way to get my (non-wordpress) site's form to have form controls that look similar to the ones in Wordpress 3.8:

[image]

I've been looking at the page in Dev tools and can't really figure out how they did it.  I've been looking online for something like this, but all solutions are very elaborate and I'm trying to keep things simple as my site has a lot of forms.

Comment: What is so special with them? Looks like standard input type radio and checkbox. `<label><input type='radio'>Full text</label'>`

Comment: They are flat, with inner shadows and the dot and the check mark are a custom color.  Ordinary form controls just look like however the OS and browser render them.  These look like my screenshot across platform and browser.

Comment: Ok, they use javascript, css and images to enhance the ui. Search for "html enhance input radio" and you will find multiple examples.

Comment: In certain situations you can do the trick completely without Javascript and images, by the way: http://www.manuel-strehl.de/dev/on_replacing_checkboxes_with_CSS3. The above looks like it would match.